AWS FPGA Kernel Refuses to Load
I am having an issue with a program running on an Amazon F1 FPGA instance.
When I run the program, the program gives me an error message without programming the FPGA and I'm not sure why because the FPGA appears to be operational.
When I run it with the environment variable XCL_EMULATION_MODE=hw (Without the variable, it appears to run on a CPU core, and it doesn't look like the FPGA is utilized.):
Loading kernel... terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error' what(): Unexected error creating shim library name Aborted (core dumped)
This is odd because the Hello World example runs fine on hardware and so does the first example here: https://github.com/Xilinx/Vitis-AWS-F1-Developer-Labs/tree/master. This is the code I'm trying to run: https://github.com/thiago-monteiro/HLSBitNet/tree/main. (Kernel is forward.cpp.)
